# EF Map list property to single column in different table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first-mapping

I have the following situation:

I have a table 'Product' which has

```
Id | Name
```

Then I have another table Product_Vendor which has

```
Id | Product_Id | Vendor_Id
```

where Product_Id is a foreign key to Product.Id. Now in my Entity class code, I want the Product entity to have a property

```
List<Guid> Vendors { get; set; }
```

Which contains all the Vendor_Id's that corresponds with the Product_id in Product_Vendor. The thing is, the Vendor_Id is a Guid that comes from a table that is in another database so it technically is not a foreign key, just a uniqueidentifier field with no constraints.

How can I map this using fluent api mapping in my ProductEntity EntityConfiguration? I use C# and SQL. I hope this is a bit clear, more information can be provided if needed :-)

Comment: You can map a Many to Many property using the Fluent API as can be seen in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927446/6787641

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of linked 1-n elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447212/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-linked-1-n-elements)

Comment: I could copy and paste my answer from above SO post :)

Comment: You might want to look at this answer here. Essentially what you want is a many-many mapping
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927446/6787641

Comment: I did provide this as an answer, but the SO mafia decided I was being far too helpful:)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but as the Vendor table is in another database a normal many-to-many mapping is not possible here. But I guess what I need to do isn't really possible since it technically isn't a relational mapping but rather a query.

Comment: You might be able to do something with a stored procedure, perform the linking inside the stored procedure